# Dependency selection for DS components using configuration properties

Tags: java, osgi, declarative-services

Consider this situation:

- Within a network management system which is fully OSGi based and has heavily employed service layer SOA concepts, it's decided to transform NE management modules to DS components.
- There is a DS component in the role of a configuration sub-agent that tracks network resources and when the time is right, it configures management components to attend to that resource through factory configuration per [Neil's article](http://njbartlett.name/2010/07/19/factory-components-in-ds.html).
- The set of components is not known, but their configuration factory PID is published by a specialized bundle that installs the management component.
- Let say there are **static**, **reluctant** and **mandatory** dependencies among some of these management components, for instance `C2` needs `C1`. As there are many resources being tacked by the NMS, there are potentially many instances of `C1` and `C2` out there. Therefore, `C2` has to bind to its matching `C1`.
- The criteria for this selection is a key, e.g., `resource-key` which is generated per resource by the configuration agent and is supplied to each component through their (factory) configuration properties.

Now, here is my question:

**Question:**  Since configuration properties are only available after component's activation, how can `C2` bind to a proper `C1` before being activated, given the nature of their relationship?

I know this question is asked with different flavors and has some witty answers like [Dynamic target queries in OSGi with DS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356226/dynamic-target-queries-in-osgi-with-ds) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bndtools-users/nHtJLaksWMk). But what is missing from all those answers is the fact that there are scenarios where dynamic configuration for each instance of a component are not *a priori* known, or at least not until it is activated.

**Proposal:**
Since we had to solve this, the only *elegant* and *OSGi-acceptable* answer I could think of was to introduce *dynamic macro expansion* at reference bind time which allows something like this for `C2`:

```
@Reference(target="(resource-key=${resource-key})")
protected void bindC1(C1 c1)
{
    // some binding code
}
```

We have chosen to stick with *Equinox DS* for the time being (yeah, I know!), therefore, I've patched their SCR and now `C2` will bind to proper instance of `C1` with `resource-key` property matching that of `C2`'s by expanding **`${resource-key-value}`** using `C2`'s own configuration. This value is not (yet) accessible inside `C2.bindC1()`.

I'm wondering why such a handy facility is missing from every SCR I've tested with. What I've demonstrated here could well be expanded to use various sources other than just component's configuration properties. But why there is at least no evidence of a formal proposal for such feature? Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that you need such a feature. Since you supply `resource-key` through the component properties, why not just supply the target property for the C1 reference, `C1.target` (See 112.6.2.1 in the DS spec), which references the resource-key value the same way?

`C1.target` = `(resource-key=xxx)`

The value of the `C1.target` component property will override the `target` information in the `C1` Reference annotation.

Sure the value, `(resource-key=xxx)`, is a little more complex than `xxx` but this is much easier than some macro expansion feature.

Comment: Clearly because of decoupling; we (the configurator agent) don't want to impose how components are going to select their dependencies. They are free to choose their `target` as they wish. This is another flexibility we wish components to have. Providing them `target` restricts their development.

Comment: Moreover, the configuration agent does not need to know all the details of the component, supposedly how `C2` requires `C1`. It just supplies them with a very basic but critical set of configurations so that they can bind their dependencies and become active.

Comment: My point is that in your example, you are setting the resource-key property whose value selects some C1 service into the configuration of a C2. And if you can do that, you can also just as easily set the the C1.target property whose value select some C1 service into the configuration of a C2. There is no practical difference other than not requiring some macro replacements language be invented.

Comment: In this design, the configurator serves a general purpose of discovering network resources by retrieving a set of properties and dispatching them in the form of some configuration objects with known PIDs which include `resource-key` and some other features. It does not know how these properties are going to be used, which components are going to use them and how these components are related. We actually came across this idea by studying OSGi, 7 years a go and appreciating its promotion of *decoupling* (SoC).

Comment: (continued) In this atmosphere, configurator is not going to know `C1` or `C2` (therer are actually 40 different components in the system), leave the fact that how complex they require one another (based on firmware version of the discovered resource) and even know that `C2` has a reference *named* `C1`.

Comment: In my opinion, the issue here is the time span between component creation and its activation. In this span, DS specification does not specify how components may access their own set of minimal requirements, which I think include the BundleContext (of this component) and its configuration properties. I think this needs to be addressed somehow.